# ngDialog - Body class not changing on open/close of a dialog in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ng-dialog

I'm using ngDialog to display a pop-up in my AngularJS web app. I'm having a peculiar problem that only happens in Chrome about 20% of the time. Firefox and IE don't have this issue.

When the dialog is open, ngDialog appends `class="ngdialog-open"` to the `body` tag, like so: `<body class="ngdialog-open">`. When the dialog is closed, `body` reverts to `<body class>`. These must exist as expected to not have the problem.

However, in Chrome this change only happens about 80% of the time. The other 20% of the time, the `body` tag will continue to have the `dialog-open` class even once the dialog is closed. Or vice versa - I've opened the dialog, but the `body` does not get the new class. When this happens, I have to click on the page to interact with it. For example, if I wanted to click a text input, I would need to double click on it to interact with it. However, once I've done that initial click, the `body class` changes to the expected value and I can interact with the page as expected.

Comment: never used that module but whenever problems like this arise always best to check issue tracker in repo. Chances are others have similar issues and also check version compatibilities

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for the advice, switched the newest version and it is not quite as finicky now. feel free to post that as an answer for some points...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt check repo issue tracker as well as check version compatibility between angular being used and module dependency.

I do know that angular 1.4 `ngAnimate` rewrite did introduce breaking changes in some modules